# Select Max Date or Highest Date Available

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables.
`Table_A` contains date values from 2020-07-01 - 2021-06-30
`Table_B` contains dates values from 2021-07-01 to whatever todays date is.

I want to select the highest date value from `Table_A` that is at least 365 days older than the higher date value in `Table_B`.

For example:

If the highest date value in `Table_B` is 2021-08-16, then I want 2020-08-16 from `Table_A`.

If 2020-08-16 is not available in `Table_A` due to some software problem we were having at the time, network issue, etc, I want the next highest available.

Here is the code I am using so far:

```
select top 10000000
    a.[Report Date]
from
    [Table_A] as a
where
    a.[Report Date] <= (select max(b.[Report Date]) from [Table_B] as b) AND
    cast((select max(b.[Report Date]) from [Table_B] as b) as date) - cast(a.[Report Date] as date) >= 365
group by
    a.[Report Date]
order by
    a.[Report Date]
```

The error message I'm getting is

> Operand Data Type date is invalid for subtract operator.

I don't even know if this code will work, was just testing since I'm still developing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: instead of using subtract operator use ```datediff``` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you think to complicated. Simply select the maximum a.date where a.date <= max(b.date) - 365 days:

```
select
  max(a.[Report Date])
from [Table_A] as a
where a.[Report Date] <=
        (select dateadd(day, -365, max(b.[Report Date])) from [Table_B] as b);
```

Comment: You wrote the wrong number of days in your post, but the right number in your code. That works though, thank you!

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected this. A typical German mistake to confuse the two places, because we read 365 as three hundred five-and-sixty in our language :-(